# Rust appending unicode escape before creating new struct

Tags: rust

I am reading from a file and then creating a struct from those values.

```rust
let file = File::open(self.get_state_name().add(".sky")).unwrap();
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
for (_, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
    let line = line.unwrap();
    let key_value = line.split("`").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let key = key_value[0].to_string();
    let data = key_value[1].to_string();
    self.set(key, data);
}
```

Set function creates a new struct named model

```rust
let model = Model::new(key, data);
```

New function just returns a struct named model:

```rust
pub fn new(key: String, data: String) -> Model {
   Model { key, data }
}
```

Value of key is prefixed with unicode escapes like:

```rust
Model {
    key: "\u{f}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}Test",
    data: "Test Data",
},
```

**Update**:
Tried saving only ascii characters:

```rust
pub fn new(key: String, data: String) -> Model {
   let key = key.replace(|c: char| !c.is_ascii(), "");
   println!("Key: {}", key);
   Model { key, data }
}
```

**Update**:
Saving file

```rust
let mut file = File::create(name.add(".sky")).unwrap();
for i in &data {
    let data = i.to_string();
    let bytes = bincode::serialize(&data).unwrap();
    file.write_all(&bytes).expect("Unable to write to file");
}
```

`.to_string()` methods on struct

```rust
pub(crate) fn to_string(&self) -> String {
    format!("{}`{}\n", self.key, self.data)
}
```

Here is key is without unicode escapes. It happens during `Model { key, data }` line.

Same doesn't happen when directly setting value not reading from file.
How to remove this and why is this happening?

Comment: How did you save the file? It looks like you saved the value `15` as a 64-bit little endian value before the string itself.

Comment: @CodesInChaos updated with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing the code using `bincode::serialize` but read back the data not with `bincode::deserialize` but using `BufReader`.

In order to properly serialize the string in a binary fashion, the encoder adds additional information about the data it stores.

If you know that only strings compatible with `BufReader#lines` will be processed, you can also use [`String#as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes) when writing it to a file. Note that this will cause problems for some inputs, notably newline characters and others.